# How do I move photos from Photos to Documents without converting from RAW to JPG?

Tags: photos, photos.app

I bought a Mac this week. I uploaded several hundred pictures into Photos. I then drag and dropped them into folders under Documents (for organizational purposes). Unfortunately, the RAW files were automatically converted from RAW to JPG when I did this. How do I move the pictures from Photos to Documents without this automatic conversion taking place? Thank you.